# "uninitialized constant Encoding" using rvm, ruby 1.9.2, bundler and passenger

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, encoding, rvm, bundler, ruby-1.9.2

I am at wit's end here and am turning to you all for some help on this f*#$^ encoding issue.

I am running on a private server with root permissions on Dreamhost. Here is a bit about my environment and versions.

```
$ `which ruby` -v
ruby 1.9.2p180 (2011-02-18 revision 30909) [x86_64-linux]
$ `which bundle` -v
Bundler version 1.0.15
$ `which rails` -v
Rails 3.0.9
```

Aside from this error, my rails app runs fine without issue. However, when I try to change the encoding a string by using the `encode` method it:

```
NoMethodError: undefined method `encode' for "foobar":String
```

`encode` [should be](http://ruby-doc.org/core/classes/String.html#M001113) defined but it is not! `Encoding` is found if I try in `irb`:

```
$ irb
ruby-1.9.2-p180 :001 > Encoding
 => Encoding
ruby-1.9.2-p180 :002 > "foobar".encode('utf-8')
 => "foobar"
```

But if I try using the rails console through bundle exec, `Encoding` is not found:

```
$ bundle exec rails c staging
Loading staging environment (Rails 3.0.9)
ruby-1.9.2-p180 :001 > Encoding
NameError: uninitialized constant Encoding
    from /[REDACTED]/shared/bundle/ruby/1.8/gems/aws-s3-0.6.2/lib/aws/s3/extensions.rb:206:in `const_missing'
    from (irb):1
ruby-1.9.2-p180 :002 > "foobar".encode('utf-8')
    NoMethodError: undefined method `encode' for "foobar":String
```

Obviously the setup is not loading something correctly but I am not sure where to look to figure it out. What am I missing here?

**UPDATE 6/19/2011**

As Ryan Bigg pointed out, it is curious that the directory path for the gems is `1.8`. However, running `bundle exec` shows that bundler is using the correct ruby and rails versions:

```
$ bundle exec which ruby
/path/to/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p180/bin/ruby
$ bundle exec `which ruby` -v
ruby 1.9.2p180 (2011-02-18 revision 30909) [x86_64-linux]
$ bundle exec which rails
/path/to/shared/bundle/ruby/1.8/bin/rails
$ bundle exec `which rails` -v
Rails 3.0.9
```

Clearly something is wonky here… I just don't know what.

**UPDATE 6/26/2011**

Seamus asked for the [$LOAD_PATH](https://gist.github.com/1047295)…

**UPDATE 6/26/2011 (later)**

Seamus asked for the [Gemfile.lock](https://gist.github.com/1048157) and the [pp ENV](https://gist.github.com/1048155)… In the `ENV` output, I found that the `GEM_PATH` was not correct. In my `staging.rb` environment file, I have:

```
GEM_HOME = "/home/[REDACTED]/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180@[REDACTED]"
GEM_PATH = "/home/[REDACTED]/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180@[REDACTED]:/home/[REDACTED]/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180@global"
```

…which is obviously not being honored. Nowhere else in my code is there a mention of `GEM_HOME` or `GEM_PATH`

**UPDATE 6/27/2011**

Seamus asked for the [`.bundle/config`](https://gist.github.com/1049412) contents…

Comment: Your `/shared/bundle/ruby/1.8/` gives it away: your console is still using 1.8, not 1.9.

Comment: But the prompt says "ruby-1.9.2-p180"?

Comment: @coneybeare: But the `/shared/bundle/ruby/1.8` says 1.8? Remove `/shared/bundle/ruby/1.8` if you're not using it. You may have to run `bundle install` again.

Comment: I did try removing it and redoing the bundle install --deployment (the same line that cap deploy uses)… it creates the gems under ruby/1.8 despite having the 1.9 gems loaded (as shown above when using bundle exec).  The line cap uses to install is: "bundle install --gemfile /path/to/releases/20110619032757/Gemfile —path /path/to/shared/bundle --deployment --quiet --without development test"

Comment: When you're in the console, what is $LOAD_PATH ?

Comment: $LOAD_PATH is nil in bash and in the rails console

Comment: That is very strange... it should be an array of directories (strings). Both $: and $LOAD_PATH are nil in rails console??

Comment: nope, my mistake, i was doing ENV["LOAD_PATH"]. Updated the answer

Comment: Thanks for that gist. What are the contents of ENV when you're in console? (Use require "pp"; pp ENV) Also, what are the contents of Gemfile.lock?

Comment: Is the aws-s3 gem really in your Gemfile? Maybe you first installed the aws-s3 gem to the system in ruby 1.8 environment and then you forgot to add the aws-s3 gem to the Gemfile.

Comment: Yes, the aws-s3 gem is in the Gemfile and Gemfile.lock. I will post gists on this.

Comment: I updated with a few of the requested gists.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**UPDATED** same idea (that `GEM_HOME` is messed up), but more suggestions

Your `GEM_HOME` is messed up, **possibly because your PATH** is messed up. You could try setting the following environment variable **in your shell**

```
$ export PATH=[your current path but with rvm's ruby 1.9 at the front]
```

Then run

```
$ bundle install
```

If that doesn't work, try also setting this in your shell

```
$ export GEM_HOME=[your ruby 1.9 gem home]
```

and then re-run

```
$ bundle install
```

New ideas from this answer: [Using RVM, bundler does not install in proper gemset when gems are installed in a different ruby version](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4414936/using-rvm-bundler-does-not-install-in-proper-gemset-when-gems-are-installed-in-a)

Comment: It did not help. I removed my shared/bundle folder, and re-ran the bundle install command. It still sets it as 1.8. I think that the gem path only has 1.8 as a name, not as contents though. Inside the folder, all the gems are fine and the most current.

Comment: To be clear, the way I checked this is to edit the boot.rb file as indicated, delete the shared bundle directory, redo a bundle install, then check in rails c if Encoding existed.

Comment: Have you totally uninstalled and reinstalled the bundler gem? What are the contents of your .bundle/config file, if you have one?

Comment: I did just uninstall and re-install the gem. I updated the question with the bundle/config file. Still, it installs under 1.8 directory. It still appears to be using 1.9.2 according to the console prompt and bundle exec ruby version.

Comment: Try removing .bundle/config and Gemfile.lock and re-running bundle update.

Comment: bundle install deployment cannot be run without a Gemfile.lock file already checked in. Removing the .bundle/config file did not do anything